# Heroku issue while pushing code to the server

Tags: heroku, deployment, compiler-errors, push, heroku-cli

When you run `git push heroku master` . It shows the error as shown below. I think git is not permitting the code to push.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu14:/var/www/html/heroku/ssp/newone$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 224 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to hidden-eyrie-58569.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hidden-eyrie-58569.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hidden-eyrie-58569.git'
```

Comment: The solution to your question is in the message from the remote Server: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for giving me the idea. it worked with

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to

```
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
```

only then lunch

```
git push heroku master
```